# Simple nested for loops not working correctly in C (2D array initialization)

Tags: c, arrays, loops, matrix, 2d

I can't understand why this simple code has this strange behaviour.

`     code:

```
  int main(){

  int m[10][10];
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  for (i;i<10;i++) {

       for (j;j<10;j++)  {
                   m[i][j]=i+j;
                   printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
                   } 
        printf("\n");                      
         }  
  printf("%d ", m[4][3]);
  }
```

`

I'm expecting a matrix-like output, but the output is this:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

32678

Note that the program prints 9 empty lines before 32678  (the printed value of m[4][3], obviously it should be 7). Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where did you find a for loop like  this: `for(i;i<10;i++)`?

Comment: Well it works when there is only one loop, the initialization comes before in the code. I think it's a bad habit that I should break.

Comment: Ok @Gandi but if you initialize `i` before the loop you can write `for(;i<10;i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loops are a bit strange, in that you aren't actually assigning anything to your loop counters in your initialization expressions. For example, this:

```
for (i;i<10;i++) {
```

is unusual... I'd expect to see this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

...where `i` is set to `0` at the start of the loop.

For your outer loop, that quirk is harmless since you initialize `i` to `0` earlier in `main()`... but for your *inner* loop, it means that `j` does not start over at `0` for the second or subsequent times the loop is run, making the test expression false right away, and preventing the loop from running at all after the first iteration of the outer loop.  That leaves most of your array (everything after the first row) uninitialized.

Changing the inner loop's initialization expression as follows:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
```

should fix it.

Note that eg. `j;` instead of `j = 0;` as the initialization expression is still valid, it just doesn't *do* anything.

Answer (score 4):

```
   for (i;i<10;i++)
      {
               for (j;j<10;j++)
```

In these both loops initialize `i`and `j` to `0`. And you will get matrix like output.See working program here -https://ideone.com/cm3vV9

Declare like this

```
 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
         for (j=0;j<10;j++)
```

You get `9` lines between values because `printf("\n");` run `9` time inside loop and then value of `m[4][3]` is printed (which is ofcourse not its value it throws just some random value ).

Comment: ..which would have been blatantly obvious with a minimal debugging attempt:(

Comment: The answer is blatantly obvious now that I see it. I've been at last 8 hours searching for similar problem before asking here, but somehow my brain didn't notice the j=0, i don't know why. I would have been searching for the entire week, maybe without noticing the problem. Sometimes these black-out happen, at least they happen to me. (However, thank you for teaching me the word "blatantly",english is not my mother tongue, it's the first time i see it).

Answer (score 3):

The reason `m[4][3]` is printing `32678` is because that portion of the array had not yet been initialized when you called `printf()` during the first iteration of the outer loop.

The inner loop code is ending after one iteration because you never initialize the loop counter `j` to 0 after each iteration of `i`.  Use this code instead:

```
int main() {
    int m[10][10];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            m[i][j] = i + j;
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        } 
        printf("\n");                      
    }  
}
```

Comment: He is working in c and the declarations in the for-loop-head wont work.

Comment: This doesn't suprise me, but the logic he is using in his loop is an even bigger problem.

Comment: At least his programm will compile and output something.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `for (j;j<10;j++)` carefully: `j` is not reset to zero on a subsequent iteration of `i`. Remedy this with `for (int j = 0, j < 10, ++j)` etc. and similarly for `i`. Drop the wider scope declarations of `i` and `j`.

The declaration inside a `for` loop construct has been part of C for a while now; keeping variable scope as local as possible helps program stability.